# Retrieve options for the second drop down box from DB based on first Drop down box

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently working on a small project. I have to retrieve some data from a DB (MySQL) and insert it into a webpage as a select (Drop Down box). The code I have written in PHP is:

```
<?php
// Connect to the db.
require ('mysqli_connect.php');

// Make the query:
$q = "SELECT employee_name from employee where dept_id=3 ORDER BY employee_id ASC"; 

// Run the query.
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

if ($r) // If it ran OK, display the records. 
{ 
     echo '<select name="employee_name">';

     // Fetch and print all the records:
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) 
     {
          echo '<option value="'.$row['employee_name'] . '>"'.$row['employee_name'] .'</option>';
          echo "</select>";                         
     }

}

mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the resources.
mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
?>
```

When I execute the query in MySQL console, it returns the correct output. [It is a list of five names].

Can you help me find the error?